# How do we address region-specific terminology?

Tags: discussion, terminology

In [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/what-are-the-differences-between-a-child-who-was-born-normally-and-via-sectio-ca) a user asked about sectio caesare.  I am not familiar with that term, and instead know it as caesarian section.

However, I do not wish to assume that the version I am familiar with is more appropriate than the one the OP used.

I have posted a related question in [EU&L](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75894/is-sectio-caesare-an-appropriate-english-alternative-to-caesarian-section).

In the meantime, though, how do we want to handle multiple versions of common parenting terminology that may differ from region to region?  Do we want to leave them as whatever the OP uses, or try and standardize?

If we standardize, what do we use as the basis for the standard?  Most common use?  How do we determine that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, I recommend relying on (the English version of) Wikipedia.

In this case, the common term is clearly caesarian section (as the answers to your EL&U question also indicate).

All else being equal, standardizing on the most commonly-used English expression should be preferred, since that's what folks looking to find the question will be using.